# Beta Binomial model - how to derive the posterior distribution

Tags: probability, machine-learning, bayesian, beta-function

I am trying to work with the **Beta Binomial model** for Machine Learning and Bayesian probability theory.

Here we have the **Likelihood** for the Beta-Binomial model:

[image: Beta_Binomial_likelihood]

Here we have the **Prior**:

[image: Beta_Binomial_prior]

And if we were to multiply them, we would get this:

[image: posterior_1]

**My first question is this:** The textbook says that the prior distribution is proportional to the likelihood times the prior itself:

[image: proportional_prior]

**But how is this possible?** The $p(D | \theta)$ term is NOT CONSTANT - it varies as $\theta$ varies (and NOT necessarily proportionally with $p(\theta)$), correct?

**And my second question is this:** The textbook also says that the **posterior** is this:

[image: proportional_posterior]

I've already tried to derive this, but no luck. Could someone give me a couple steps in the right direction for this as well? Where do the 1 Bin and 2 Beta terms come from?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have expected the book to say the posterior is proportional to the likelihood times the prior so in your notation $$p(\theta \mid \mathcal{D}) \propto p(\mathcal{D}\mid \theta)\,p( \theta)$$ and your final line seems to be missing a symbol

$$p(\theta \mid \mathcal{D}) \propto \text{Bin}(N_1\mid \theta, N_0+N_1) \, \text{Beta}(\theta \mid a,b) \propto \text{Beta}(\theta \mid N_1+a,N_0+b) $$

with

- the binomial $p(\mathcal{D}\mid \theta)=\text{Bin}(N_1\mid \theta, N_0+N_1)$ being proportional to the likelihood  and
- the Beta $p( \theta) =\text{Beta}(\theta \mid a,b)$ being the conjugate prior for $\theta$ and
- the Beta $p(\theta \mid \mathcal{D}) = \text{Beta}(\theta \mid N_1+a,N_0+b) $ being the posterior distribution for $\theta$

Comment: Hey Henry, the book says exactly what I put in my first question (that was an unedited screenshot). Was it a typo? It does not make any sense

Comment: @Josh Does what I have written make sense? Could the book have typos like this?

Comment: What you have written makes much more sense than the textbook.  I'm not sure whether or not the book is likely to have these kinds of typos - and the fact that I'm not sure is what's bothering me. And also, every one of the images that you see in my question were screenshots, so when you added that symbol you said was missing, it looks as if you uncovered yet another typo